# How to transfer AspWebform to another machine

Tags: vb.net

I have developped Windows applications with Visual Studio for many years. When the program is ready, I can copy the compiled .exe file to another computer to test it.
Now I start creating a webform application. But how can I test it on another computer. There is no .exe file, what files do I have  to copy ?

Thanks for your help